# Distribution of Product of Matrices holding Multivariate Random Normal Variable Observations

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

We have matrices $\boldsymbol{A}$ and $\boldsymbol{B}$ that hold observations from multivariate normal distributions. Each matrix represents $\boldsymbol{n}$ observations of $\boldsymbol{m}$ variables from a multivariable normal distribution. (The rows are the observations and each column can be considered as representing one random variable. Hence, each column in each matrix is $\boldsymbol{n}$ observations of one of the $\boldsymbol{m}$ random variables stored in that matrix.)

We can assume independence between $\boldsymbol{A}$ and $\boldsymbol{B}$ to simplify things.

$$
\boldsymbol{A_{n*m}}\sim\mathcal{N}\left(\boldsymbol{\mu_{1}},\boldsymbol{\varSigma_{1}}\right)
$$
$$
\boldsymbol{B_{n*m}}\sim\mathcal{N}\left(\boldsymbol{\mu_{2}},\boldsymbol{\varSigma_{2}}\right)
$$

**Question One (Primary Question):**

What are the distributions of $\boldsymbol{AB^{T}}$ and $\boldsymbol{A^{T}B}$?

**Question Two:**

What are some other useful well known properties of $\boldsymbol{AB^{T}}$ and $\boldsymbol{A^{T}B}$?

**Question Three:**

Are there general techniques to find properties of the product of Matrices holding Random Variable Observations from any Distribution? For example, either or both of  $\boldsymbol{A}$ and $\boldsymbol{B}$ could hold observations from multivariate log normal distributions.

Please let me know if the question is not well framed or if I am not using the correct notation, or if any further details are needed.

Comment: Clarify if the columns or the rows have the given distributions? or the vectorized matrix has those distributions? If the columns (or rows) have the given distributions are they independent?

Comment: @S.B I have updated the question now. If more clarifications are needed, please let me know. Also, what does Vectorized Matrix mean… ?

Comment: It's still not clear what are those distributions? Are they distributions for the columns (or rows) of $A$ and $B$  or something else? A vectorization simply mean to put the entries if the matrix in a vector (column-wise or row-wise). By the way, I doubt that you can find a simple distribution for the general case. However, you might be able to say something about the general behavior of those product matrices , depending on the assumptions made.

Comment: @S.B. Just looking at one Matrix first, $A$ it holds $n$ observations from a multivariable normal distribution with $m$ random variables. Each column is $n$ observations of one of the $m$ random variables. Please let me know if this is clear. The case of the normal distribution is the main one; the others are secondary questions ...